# How to Toggle between two values from table rows in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a table name `[NavBar]` with these columns:

```
Id [int]
Name [nvarchar]
DisplayOrder [int]
```

Sample data:

```
Id   Name   DisplayOrder
---------------------------
 1   Home        1
 2   Products    2
 3   Contact     3
 4   Career      4
```

I want to write a query to update `DisplayOrder` between two rows whose displayOrder is next higher display order value of a given row.

For example `Contact = 4, Career = 3`

Expected output:

```
1  Home      1
2  Products  2
3  Contact   4
4  Career    3
```

How do I perform update operation to toggle between two rows display order of two concurrent rows (order by Displayorder) ?

Input parameter: `Id` of one row only

Comment: Input parameter should be the ID of the row and the position you want to show it at, right?

Comment: I mean If input parameter Id  = 3 (i.e Contact) then I want to toggle with next displayorder row(i.e career i.e 4)

Comment: What do you mean by "Input parameter: Id of one row only" ??

Comment: I means the id only specified to select and update. @Krishnraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the Displayorder from your input, and from your next record
Than you can update it all.
Its a bit complicated but I tested it it works.
Also this way you can avoid troubles when the DisplayOrder has gaps in it.

```
declare @InputID int = 3
declare @DisplayOrderInput int
declare @ID int
declare @DisplayOrder int

select @DisplayOrderInput = DisplayOrder from NavBar where ID = @InputID

select top 1
       @ID = ID,
       @DisplayOrder = DisplayOrder
from   NavBar
where  DisplayOrder > (select DisplayOrder from NavBar where ID = @InputID)
order by DisplayOrder

update NavBar set DisplayOrder = @DisplayOrder where ID = @InputID
update NavBar set DisplayOrder = @DisplayOrderInput where ID = @ID

select * from NavBar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE NavBar  
SET     DisplayOrder =  CASE  
                        WHEN DisplayName  = @row1 THEN (select DipslayOrder from NavBar where DisplayName = @row2)  
                        WHEN DisplayName  = @row2 THEN (select DipslayOrder from NavBar where DisplayName = @row1) 
                        END 
WHERE   DisplayName IN (@row1, @row2);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: how do I execute this query ? what are the values of @row1,@row2 or DidplayName ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Try with this.. For any id it will work :

DECLARE @INPUT INT=3 

UPDATE A 
SET    A.DISPLAYORDER = B.DISPLAYORDER 
FROM   #TEMP A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, 
                          NAME, 
                          CASE 
                            WHEN ID = @INPUT THEN DISPLAYORDER + 1 
                            WHEN ID = @INPUT + 1 THEN DISPLAYORDER - 1 
                            ELSE DISPLAYORDER 
                          END DISPLAYORDER 
                   FROM   #TEMP)B 
               ON A.ID = B.ID    


    Output :

    ID  NAME    DISPLAYORDER 
    1   Home        1
    2   Products    2
    3   Contact     4
    4   Career      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
-- 1) Get Current row's displayorder and Next Row's id in Temp table
SELECT nb1.DisplayOrder, nb2.id 
into #TempNavBar
FROM [NavBar] nb1
INNER JOIN [NavBar] nb2 ON nb1.id = nb2.id - 1
WHERE nb1.Id = 3

-- 2) Update Actual table by using Self join on Next row
UPDATE nb1
    SET nb1.DisplayOrder = nb2.DisplayOrder
FROM [NavBar] AS nb1
INNER JOIN [NavBar] AS nb2 ON nb1.id = nb2.id - 1
WHERE nb1.Id = 3

-- 3). Update Actual table by joining it with temp table
UPDATE nb1
    SET nb1.DisplayOrder = tmp2.DisplayOrder
FROM [NavBar] AS nb1
INNER JOIN #TempNavBar AS tmp2 ON nb1.id = tmp2.id

-- Cleanup operation
DROP TABLE #TempNavBar
```

What i have done here is join the `NavBar` table with itself but on next row id and fetch the current row's `DisplayOrder` column and next row's `id` column value and insert it into temp table.

In the second query, i have update the value of current row's `displayOrder` value with its next row's value.

In the third query, i have update the `displayOrder` value with the temp table `DisplayOrder` value by joining the [NavBar] table with temp table.

**Result**

```
Id  Name    DisplayOrder
------------------------
1   Home        1
2   Products    2
3   Contact     4
4   Career      3
```